# Refresh token in Spartacus after user does an action

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I want to ask if someone knows a possibility to refresh token after user do any kind of activity. Right now token gets created after user logs in but it never get refresh, only if token is expired and user tries to do a request, this functionality can be found in AuthInterceptor but in our current project we automatically log out if expired_at is less than current Date.

Does someone can give me some guidance? I have tried creating another interceptor and call function handleExpiredAccessToken from class AuthHttpHeaderService but no good response, my token tries to refresh many times ending in a loop.

Also we tried refreshing the token 5 minutes before the expiration time and refresh headers for request like follow code:

```
 const stream = this.authStorageService.getToken();
    stream.subscribe((tokenData) => {
      if(tokenData.expires_at && ( +tokenData.expires_at - 300000 < new Date().getTime())){
        this.oAuthLibWrapperService.refreshToken();
      }
      if(tokenData.access_token){
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `${tokenData.token_type || 'Bearer'} ${tokenData.access_token}`,
          },
        });
      }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can leverage this back-end configuration property: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2105/en-US/3d3ea6a4d5fa486aa324ce278fa2afc3.html?q=oauthauthorizationserver.tokenServices.reuseRefreshToken

According to the docs, every time the access token expires (and Spartacus automatically refreshes it), the server will generate a new refresh token. I'm assuming this means the validity of the new refresh token will be reset (easy to check).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a silent refresh like in this [repo](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards). If you then call  the [silentRefresh](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/99a0ced198d1df2d5f8d51f62032c6f9b9b17f5e/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts#L1034) function of the [OAuthService](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/99a0ced198d1df2d5f8d51f62032c6f9b9b17f5e/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts) class, it will do a refresh of the token in a iframe.